# Use multiple left joins in update query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I made a select query `having count(JobDegree)>1` I used

```
Employees left join JobDegree on Employees.Id = JobDegree.employeeId
```

like following:

```
select Employees.Id, count(JobDegree.DegreeId) as 'Degrees',Contracts.Salary
from Employees
left join JobDegree on Employees.Id = JobDegree.employeeId
left join Contracts on Employees.Id = Contracts.EmployeeId
group by Employees.Id,Contracts.Salary
having COUNT(JobDegree.DegreeId) > 1
```

I want to update the salary of each employee where `count(JobDegree.Id)>1`
 by `set Salary = Salary + 100` but the salary of employee is in another table named Contracts `Contracts.Salary` 
and Contracts contain a column `Contracts.employeeId` that I want to join with 
`Employees.Id` and the **update** query confused me any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this as:

```
update c 
    set salary = c.salary + 100
from contracts c inner join 
     (select jd.employeeId
      from JobDegree jd
      group by jd.employeeId
      having count(*) > 1
     ) jd
     on jd.EmployeeId = c.EmployeeId
```

Notice that the `Employees` table itself is not needed.

Comment: I think this can help but i a have posted my answer.Thanks.

Comment: @YoussofHammoud . . . This is simpler and more performant than your answer, which is why I answered.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want

```
Update Contracts
set Salary = Salary + 100
where Contracts.employeeId in
(select Employees.Id
from Employees
left join JobDegree on Employees.Id = JobDegree.employeeId
left join Contracts on Employees.Id = Contracts.EmployeeId
group by Employees.Id,Contracts.Salary
having COUNT(JobDegree.DegreeId) > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks but my answer looks better.

Comment: The second left join is not needed any more `left join Contracts on Employees.Id = Contracts.EmployeeId` and `Contracts.Salary` in the group by is not needed also

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subquery` with `update` statement  :

```
update c 
    set c.salary = c.salary + 100
from contracts c inner join 
     (select e.id
      from Employees e left join
           JobDegree jd
           on jd.employeeId = e.id
      group by e.id
      having count(jd.DegreeId) > 1
     ) s
     on s.id = c.EmployeeId;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I tried and helped so much `in`

```
update Contracts set Salary= Salary + 100 where Contracts.EmployeeId in (
select Employees.Id
from Employees
left join JobDegree on Employees.Id = JobDegree.employeeId
group by Employees.Id
having COUNT(JobDegree.DegreeId) > 1)
```